# Java on Debian: Probable fatal error: No fonts found

Tags: java, tomcat, fonts, debian

I want to run Tomcat on Debian 5 Minimal. So I don't need a gui for my OS, it's just a pure Tomcat-Server.

Which packages do I need for my JVM to use Fonts in my applications? Im drawing texts in Graphics2D and am creating PDF-Files in my Java-Project.

Comment: your question is which api to use to create PDF or how to make debian use your font in your code?

Comment: The second one. The application itself works perfectly on systems which do have a windowManager installed. So I think my debian-installation is missing some packages

Comment: Probably. the fonts used by java can be found in the jre/lib/fontconfig.properties which is usually a softlink to the actual font file but is a place for you to start.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I dont know what the problem really was, but apt-get upgrade helped..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Graphics2D and anything in the `java.awt.*` or `java.swing.*` packages require a GUI to do its drawing.

This is a problem on most headless servers.  You have two options, and try them in this order:

1. Use the system property "java.awt.headless" and set that to "true"
   `java -Djava.awt.headless=true` or `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");`
2. Install the XWindows Virtual Frame Buffer (xvfb) on your server.  This keeps the server headless, but provides the XWindows primitives needed to draw on a virtual screen.  It is far from optimized (no graphics acceleration), but it will allow your system to work again.

The `java.awt.headless` option was introduced with Java 1.4.  See: http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/

In the event that does not work, install the XVFB package and configure it to create a virtual frame buffer large enough to do your drawing.

Answer (score 3):

I had similar problem on CentOS, after crunching for a solution..
I solved this problem by installing fonts like follows:

```
  sudo yum install bitmap*
  sudo yum install dejavu-lgc*
  sudo yum install bitstream-vera*
```

Answer (score 1):

I fixed this by installing some fonts (under Ubuntu) by:

> apt-get install msttcorefonts

They should be installed in `/usr/share/fonts/truetype/`.

Dont forget to restart Tomcat if you use it.

Answer (score 1):

None of the answers above worked for me on a Amazon Linux AMI with OpenJDK 1.6.0_20.  However this worked:

```
sudo yum install dejavu*
ln -s /usr/share/fonts/dejavu /usr/share/fonts/dejavu-lgc
```

The first line installs some default fonts, and the second ensures that Java finds them.  More at http://brandon.fuller.name/archives/2011/09/12/00.05.15/

Answer (score 1):

I encountered this issue with Atlassian Bamboo recently. On Scientific Linux all that I was required to do was:

sudo yum install dejavu*

(Unlike mkvalsvik I did not need to make a symlink).

Answer (score 0):

For me, this has solved it: https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=708201
Basically the 'java' package did not depend on 'fontconfig', which had to be manually installed.