# Having problems with Apache Batik library on AWS ElasticBeanstalk Instance

Tags: java, fonts, amazon-web-services, headless, batik

I am using AWS Elasti Beanstalk to power one of my apps. In this I need to export a svg document to png,jpg, pdf etc. For this I use Apache Batik library. This provides excellent output on my local dev workstation but as soon as I deploy it on the EBS I start getting errors, all related to fonts.

The error stacktrace was -

```
Caused by: java.lang.Error: Probable fatal error:No fonts found. 
    at sun.font.FontManager.getDefaultPhysicalFont(FontManager.java:1088) 
    at sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFont(FontManager.java:960) 
    at sun.font.FontManager.findOtherDeferredFont(FontManager.java:899) 
    at sun.font.FontManager.findDeferredFont(FontManager.java:916) 
    ...
    at sun.font.FontManager.findFont2D(FontManager.java:1904) 
    at sun.font.FontManager.initialiseDeferredFonts(FontManager.java:792) 
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.loadFonts(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:468)
    at sun.awt.X11GraphicsEnvironment.loadFonts(X11GraphicsEnvironment.java:925) 
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.loadFontFiles(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:498) 
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getInstalledFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:721) 
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:746) 
    at sun.java2d.SunGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(SunGraphicsEnvironment.java:773) 
    at sun.java2d.HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.getAvailableFontFamilyNames(HeadlessGraphicsEnvironment.java:99) 
    at org.apache.batik.gvt.font.FontFamilyResolver.(FontFamilyResolver.java:74) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.getFontList(SVGTextElementBridge.java:1529) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.getAttributeMap(SVGTextElementBridge.java:1610) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.fillAttributedStringBuffer(SVGTextElementBridge.java:902) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.buildAttributedString(SVGTextElementBridge.java:856) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.computeLaidoutText(SVGTextElementBridge.java:636)
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.buildGraphicsNode(SVGTextElementBridge.java:292) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(GVTBuilder.java:224) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(GVTBuilder.java:171) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(GVTBuilder.java:82) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:208) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(ImageTranscoder.java:92) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(XMLAbstractTranscoder.java:142) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(SVGAbstractTranscoder.java:156)
```

So I tried installing fonts as [one other stackoverflow answer suggests.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4438839/java-on-debian-probable-fatal-error-no-fonts-found) But this gave me a new error stacktrace -

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: 
Could not initialize class org.apache.batik.gvt.font.FontFamilyResolver 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.getFontList(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.getAttributeMap(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.fillAttributedStringBuffer(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.buildAttributedString(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.computeLaidoutText(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.SVGTextElementBridge.buildGraphicsNode(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildGraphicsNode(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.buildComposite(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.bridge.GVTBuilder.build(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.image.ImageTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.XMLAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source) 
    at org.apache.batik.transcoder.SVGAbstractTranscoder.transcode(Unknown Source)
```

I dont understand why is this happening. Then I set `System.setProperty("java.awt.headless", "true");` just before I make a call to batik's transcoder. But this also generate the above error message. I am running out of options.

Am I missing something? Can I do anything to add more context to this? Thanks for the help.

Comment: running into the same issue myself, if you figure anything out please update us

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally resolved this problem by installing Sun JDK & using it to power my tomcat server.

Comment: It's been a few years, can you confirm that this is still an issue with non-Oracle JDKs?

Answer (score 2):

I added the following dependency to my maven pom.xml file, and it seems to have made the class available for use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.xmlgraphics</groupId>
    <artifactId>batik-gvt</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
</dependency>
```

Note, however, that the fonts that it maps to don't always have the same dimensions as the MS core fonts (arial, times new roman, etc.) so can look kind of blocky or different than the ones they're replacing.

Comment: But this maven modification goes where? While doing build of batik library from scratch? or something else?

Comment: Our app is a J2EE Spring webapp and we use Maven (http://maven.apache.org/) to manage dependencies, build targets, etc. Basically adding this to the POM.xml as a dependency tells maven to go download the corresponding jar from the repository and make it available to the app. If you don't use Maven then I suppose just go to http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/ABC/Downloadbatikgvt17jar.htm and download the JAR and make sure it's in your JAVA path somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for replying. But that didnt work. :( I already had imported batick-gvt. But just to be sure I replaced it with the jar file that you have linked & recompiled. But still I get the same error.

Comment: Sorry I can't be of more help, but that fixed it for me. Are you sure that jar is being found in the path and whatnot? Seems like the error makes it clear that it can't find the class.

Comment: Is there any other way I can debug this? I checked different forums and many are of the opinion that NoClassDefFoundError can be a lot deceiving.