# HeadlessException thrown by Apache Batik 1.7 WMFTranscoder

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, exception, awt, batik

I use this code successfully in a Java desktop application (JUnit tests in NetBeans) to generate SVG from WMF data:

```
InputStream wmfStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(wmfBytes);
WMFTranscoder transcoder = new WMFTranscoder();
TranscoderInput wmf = new TranscoderInput(wmfStream);
ByteArrayOutputStream bos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
TranscoderOutput svg
        = new TranscoderOutput(new OutputStreamWriter(bos, "UTF-8"));
transcoder.transcode(wmf, svg);
return bos.toByteArray();
```

If I execute the conversion in GlassFish, a headless exception is thrown:

> java.awt.HeadlessException    at
>   sun.awt.HeadlessToolkit.getScreenResolution(HeadlessToolkit.java:224)
>     at
>   org.apache.batik.transcoder.ToSVGAbstractTranscoder.(ToSVGAbstractTranscoder.java:96)
>     ... 33 more

How can I use Apache Batik WMF to SVG conversion in a 'headless' Java runtime environment?

---

The accepted answer [Having problems with Apache Batik library on AWS ElasticBeanstalk Instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7940455/having-problems-with-apache-batik-library-on-aws-elasticbeanstalk-instance) suggests to use a Sun JDK. However, I am already running GlassFish 4.0.1 on Oracle JDK 1.7 u 65.

Comment: Can you just add -Djava.awt.headless=true to your JAVA_OPTS

Comment: @MikeK. if I query the property at run time - before the conversion - it is already `true`, so I guess setting it at startup does not make a difference?

Comment: well if you really can't install x windows you could set up x virtual frame buffer xvfb and then set your DISPLAY environment variable to use that.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably WMF uses fonts or such, that a headless environment does not provide. Headless meaning, a (Linux) server without GUI (X server), on which to rely for font rendering and the rest. Installing an X server Linux package should do.

Under debian alikes

```
apt-get install x-window-system
```

So the adage "for a server one does not need a graphical window manager" unfortunately is not true.

Answer (score 0):

Actually it is easy to solve - at least on my development machine, GlassFish configuration (domain.xml) needs to be changed to set

```
<jvm-options>-Djava.awt.headless=false</jvm-options>
```

Now testing on Linux with x-window-system, and will be back later with results.

Comment: ...did you get any results?